# SDO_AGGR_MBR error - inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT

Tags: php, oracle, geospatial

Hi I would like to get the extent/bounding box of a geometry in Oracle. So far I've tried SDO_AGGR_MBR() but it returns an error

> oci_fetch_array(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT

Below is my sample query

```
$sql = "SELECT SDO_AGGR_MBR(GEOM)
        FROM PROPERTY
        WHERE PRO_ID = $sel_id";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) != false) {
    $rows[] = $row[];
}
```

EDIT: 
The table is composed of IDs for primary keys, an SDO_GEOMETRY type and another ID for reference. I would like to get the extent/bounding box of the geometry similar to PostGIS ST_Extent().

Comment: Provide at least information about table types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. About the table types you mean the column types? Its only has a primary keys, an SDO_GEOMETRY and a NUMBER type.